# Настроить размер кучи, чтобы избежать OutOfMemory

Tags: java, outofmemoryerror, heap

люди.

Очень нужна ваша помощь, как так я уже не знаю, что делать. Нет алгоритма действия.

Есть код, который отправляет файлы через соап-сервис. Внутри программы файл энкодится в Base64, оборачивается SOAP-оберткой и едет через soapConnection.call().

Но, как мне кажется, это и не важно, так как проблема не в невозможности что-то отправить. На маленьких файлах программа работает отлично.
Но стоит придти файлу с размером 180мб, как программа падает.

И тут я не понимаю. В системе еще 3Гб свободной ОЗУ, всего 8гб.
Настройки JVM

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

То есть ему еще должно хватать.

Написал тестовый код, который тоже энкодит файл и складывает в неочищаемую память:

```
try{
    String path;
    path = "path_1";
    path =       "path_2";
    final int N = 100;
    List<String> inf = new ArrayList<>();
    Base64.Encoder en = Base64.getEncoder();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        String zip_str = en.encodeToString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
        inf.add(zip_str);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Чтобы посмотреть, как и когда заканчивается память...
На файле 182491 Кб программа падает уже на второй итерации, а на файле 88288 Кб (который успешно отправляется изначальной программой) - только на четвертой. Хотя разница размеров не в 4 раза...

---

В общем, я не знаю, как надо настроить JVM, чтобы код не падал даже на большом файле. Хотя какой же он большой - даже 200мб нет.
Очень прошу помочь.

---

Для тех, кто любит стектрейсы:

```
фев 01, 2021 6:29:41 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl saveChanges
SEVERE: SAAJ0540: Error during saving a multipart message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.saveChanges(MessageImpl.java:1204)
    at informatica.soap.SendSOAP.createSOAPRequest(SendSOAP.java:140)
    at informatica.soap.SendSOAP.callSoapWebService(SendSOAP.java:102)
    at run.soap.SendSOAPRun.onInputRow(SendSOAPRun.java:61)
    at informatica.run.BasicRun.allRun(BasicRun.java:34)
    at run.soap.SendSOAPRun.main(SendSOAPRun.java:108)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(ToUnknownStream.java:345)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:244)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:136)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:693)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:351)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:399)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:289)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getContentAsStream(SOAPPartImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getHeaderBytes(MessageImpl.java:1015)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.saveChanges(MessageImpl.java:1166)
    ... 5 more

CAUSE:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(ToUnknownStream.java:345)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:244)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:136)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:693)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:351)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:399)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:289)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getContentAsStream(SOAPPartImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getHeaderBytes(MessageImpl.java:1015)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.saveChanges(MessageImpl.java:1166)
    at informatica.soap.SendSOAP.createSOAPRequest(SendSOAP.java:140)
    at informatica.soap.SendSOAP.callSoapWebService(SendSOAP.java:102)
    at run.soap.SendSOAPRun.onInputRow(SendSOAPRun.java:61)
    at informatica.run.BasicRun.allRun(BasicRun.java:34)
    at run.soap.SendSOAPRun.main(SendSOAPRun.java:108)
```

И сам код:

```
public class SendSOAP {
    public static final String MY_NAMESPACE = "tem";
    public static final String MY_NAMESPACE_URI = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public static String callSoapWebService(
            String soapEndpointUrl
            , String soapAction
            , String KeyDir
            , String KeyPass
            , String data
            , int connectTimeout
            , int readTimeout
    ) throws Exception {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
        try (AutoCloseable ignored = soapConnection::close) {
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(soapEndpointUrl).openConnection();
            connection.setSSLSocketFactory(
                    SSLContextWithCert.builder()
                            .setPathToKeyStore(KeyDir)
                            .setPassword(KeyPass)
                            .getSSLContext()
                            .getSocketFactory()
            );
            connection.setHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout * 1000); // in sec
            connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeout * 1000); // in sec

            URL endPoint = new URL(null, soapEndpointUrl, new URLStreamHandler() {
                @Override
                protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) {
                    return (connection);
                }
            });
            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(
                    createSOAPRequest(soapAction, data)
                    , endPoint
            );
            ByteArrayOutputStream soapOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            soapResponse.writeTo(soapOut);
            return soapOut.toString(String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
    }

    protected static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String soapAction, String data) throws SOAPException {
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("X-Add-Data", "IncomeFromInformatica");
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);
        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(MY_NAMESPACE, MY_NAMESPACE_URI);
        // SOAP Body
        envelope.getBody()
                .addChildElement("submitEgb", MY_NAMESPACE)
                .addChildElement("Body", MY_NAMESPACE)
                .addTextNode(data);
        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        return soapMessage;
    }
}
```

```
try {
            Path zip = Paths.get(TRD_D + ZIP_FILE);
            String zip_str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Files.readAllBytes(zip));
            if (REQUEST_ERROR == null) {
                String soapMsg = SendSOAP.callSoapWebService(
                        SOAP_END_POINT_URL
                        , SOAP_ACTION
                        , KEY_DIR
                        , KEY_PASS
                        , zip_str
                        , TIMEOUT_CONNECT
                        , TIMEOUT_READ
                );
                ZIP_END_BYTE = zip_str.substring(zip_str.length() - 50);
                try {
                    REQUEST_ERROR = SoapXML.getTagValue(soapMsg, REQUEST_ERROR_TAG);
                } catch (XMLParseException e) {
                    REQUEST_ERROR = ExceptionAsString.convert(e) + "\n";
                }
                try {
                    STATUS = SoapXML.getTagValue(soapMsg, STATUS_TAG);
                } catch (XMLParseException e) {
                    STATUS = null;
                    REQUEST_ERROR += ExceptionAsString.convert(e) + "\n";
                }
                try {
                    REQUEST_NUMBER = SoapXML.getTagValue(soapMsg, REQUEST_NUMBER_TAG);
                } catch (XMLParseException e) {
                    REQUEST_NUMBER = null;
                    REQUEST_ERROR += ExceptionAsString.convert(e) + "\n";
                }
            }
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            logError(ExceptionAsString.convert(e));
            REQUEST_ERROR = "ERROR in sending SOAP\n" + ExceptionAsString.convert(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logError(ExceptionAsString.convert(e));
            REQUEST_ERROR = "SOMETHING WENT WRONG\n" + ExceptionAsString.convert(e);
        }
```

Comment: Ничего не знаю про используемые вами технологии, но вот [тут](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1668875/outofmemory-error-at-saving-soapmessage-with-attachments-in-sun-saaj-1-3), 13 лет назад поминается некий `AxiomSoapMessageFactory`, который, как утрверждается может обрабатывать вложения вплоть до гигабайта. Попробуйте его как-то в вашем коде использовать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
то есть дело в том, что сам соап-конструктор не может вывезти объем?

Comment: Я не знаю) Ни разу ничем подобным не пользовался.

Comment: Добавьте к запуску программы (не тестовой, а реальной) опции `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/some/path/to/dump.hprof` (замените путь на существующий). Когда упадет, смотрите дамп по пути указанному в опциях. Откройте дамп в jvisualvm и смотрите топ объектов по `retained size`. Это покажет, кто удерживает память и что именно удерживается.

Answer (score 1):

Ни разу не эксперт в SOAP, однако исходя из общих принципов, очевидно проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь распарсить весь файл целиком, а надо организовать декодинг в потоке, отлично мне кажется подойдет `Base64InputStream`

[Документация](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html#Base64InputStream-java.io.InputStream-)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в таких случаях проблема в том, что одни и те же данные держатся в памяти несколько раз. У вас такие этапы:

1. прочитать файл в память
2. перекодировать в base64
3. создать SOAP сообщение
4. отправить

Проблема в том, что на каждом из этапов данные из предыдущих этапов все еще могут находится в памяти. И один файл размером в 180МБ хранится несколько раз, плюс еще издержки на представление в base64 (которое съедает больше памяти), плюс издержки на xml, который используется в SOAP.

И это только то, что видно сходу. Чтоб узнать где точно держится память, нужно анализировать дамп, который генерируется в момент возникновения OOME и потом устранять проблемные места одно за другим. Как правильно написал Barmaley нужно стремиться использовать потоковую обработку. Но не только для генерации base64 представления, но и считывания файла (т.е. `Files.readAllBytes` не годится, т.к. он читает сразу весь файл целиком) и самое главное для генерации и посылки SOAP сообщения. Как генерировать и посылать SOAP сообщение потоково - это тема для отдельного вопроса.